# Golang elastic search security auto-configuration HTTP CA” certificate is not trusted

Tags: go, elasticsearch, connection

I am new to golang, trying to conenct golang with elastic search below is my code which I tried to connect using default package of go `(go-elasticsearch)`

Elastic Search Configuration

```
var _elasticSearchConfiguration = elasticsearch.Config{
    Addresses: []string{
        "https://localhost:9200",
    },
    Username: "elastic",
    Password: "123456",
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost:   10,
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: time.Second,
        DialContext:           (&net.Dialer{Timeout: time.Second}).DialContext,
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
          MinVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,
        },
    },  
}
```

usage of the above configuration

```
func GetAllJsonObjectDemos(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    _elasticsearch, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(_elasticSearchConfiguration)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error creating elasticsearch client: %v", err)
    }
    elasticSearchResponse, err := _elasticsearch.Info()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error getting response: %s", err)
    }
    defer elasticSearchResponse.Body.Close()
    log.Println(elasticSearchResponse)

}
```

I would really like to know what Am I missing here, Thanks to all the contributors.

I am expecting Connection code of golang & elastic search or any suggestion.

Comment: Try with "localhost:9200" instead of https://localhost:9200 . It should work. Also make a call to test "curl -XGET localhost:9200" to verify.

Comment: Welll using curl it working fine or using the link in postman but it fails when I am connecting it with go-elasticsearch package or oliver

Comment: Please check your username/password.

Comment: Which certificate is used in your case? self sign certificate?

Comment: username & password is also correct & I am using 256 SHA

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the error `certificate is not trusted`, you could add the certificate to [`RootCAs`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config) of tls config.

Sample codes

```golang
    rootCAs, _ := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if rootCAs == nil {
        rootCAs = x509.NewCertPool()
    }

    // Read the cert file
    certs, err := os.ReadFile("localCertFile")

    // add our cert to the system pool
    rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(certs)

    var _elasticSearchConfiguration = elasticsearch.Config{
        Addresses: []string{
            "https://localhost:9200",
        },
        Username: "elastic",
        Password: "123456",
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            MaxIdleConnsPerHost:   10,
            ResponseHeaderTimeout: time.Second,
            DialContext:           (&net.Dialer{Timeout: time.Second}).DialContext,
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                RootCAs:    rootCAs,
                MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: Well thanks for the contribution, but I tried this also, well somehow I was able to solve it by adding the SHA certificate & by restarting elasticsearch & kibana